# CFIMAP Timing out

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am trying to connect to Gmail through CFIMAP and I am getting a connection timed out error. This code works on my dev environment but not on production. I have also opened a ticket with my ISP just in case.

This is the error

```
An exception occurred when setting up mail server parameters.   
This exception was caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Connection timed out: connect; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect.
```

And this is my code:

```
<cfimap
        server = "imap.gmail.com"
        username = "surveysemail@signatureforum.com"
        action="open"
        password = "test"
        connection = "mail.test.com"
        timeout = 120>
```

I had the secure parameter in before and also the port but I removed them while testing different options. Also, I just added the timeout parameter but did not work either.

Comment: Can you connect to `imap.gmail.com` from your production server? There is probably a proxy server or something sitting between them that is not in your dev environment.

Comment: My ISP is blocking the imap port 993 so I will have to wait till they allow me to use it. Thanks @Miguel-F

Answer (score 0):

GMail is particular as to the types of connection it receives.  Generally this chalks up to a security issue because the server you're trying to log into Gmail from (at your ISP) is in a different location and has never logged in from the browser on that machine.

There's a couple of things you can do here:

First, If you have RDP access to the server at your ISP, you can log in to    Gmail from the server, then try again.

If that doesn't work, review the "Device activity and notifications" page on the Gmail    account to see if Google is blocking access from the server.     (https://myaccount.google.com/security?hl=en&pli=1#activity)

Give that a shot... most likely Gmail is seeing the activity coming from your server as erroneous and is blocking it from that front.

Comment: Please see my comment above. Thanks for your response though